# Regexp to replace mixin in Webstorm

Tags: regex, sass

I am using a mixin to theme colors in sass.

Now I want to get rid of it in my codebase and replace it with css custom properties.

the input would look like this:

```
.myClass {
  @include themify('color', 'color-primary-light');
}
```

and the output should be:

```
.myClass {
  color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

my RegEx to capture the values is : `@include themify\("(.*)", "(.*)"\);`

you can try it right here: https://regex101.com/r/qzNhjF/1

however, webstorm does not seem to recognize it in find / replace.
RegEx checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you provide this code:

```
.myClass {
  @include themify('color', 'color-primary-light');
}
```

Which will be matched by

```
@include themify\('(.*)', '(.*)'\);
```

In https://regex101.com/r/qzNhjF/1 you provide this code:

```
@include themify("color", "color-primary-light");
```

which will be matched by

```
@include themify\("(.*)", "(.*)"\);
```

Maybe you are looking for the [regex with single quotes](https://regex101.com/r/Gqe9k6/1) in you webstorm?